# Return Code of a Child Script to Parent script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I've a Parent ksh Script which inturn executes a child script like below.

```
((Demo.sh $TableName $DatFile | tee $STDLOGFILE) > $STDERRLOG 2>&1)

RC=`echo $?`
```

The return Code is not capturing correctly  when the child script(Demo.sh) is failing. It's always returning 0. I understand the Issue because I'm pushing the STDERR and STDOUT irrespective of success and failure , so it always return the Code as 0.

Please help me in capturing the actual return code of the child script.

Comment: That 0 is the return value of `tee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
 RC=$( { { Demo.sh "$TableName" "$DatFile"; echo $? >&3; } |
     tee $STDLOGFILE; } 3>&1 > $STDERRLOG 2>&1; )
```

The trouble is the classic problem of `$?` being the return value of the pipeline, which is the value returned by the last command in the pipe, namely `tee`.  In bash, this problem is often resolved using the PIPESTATUS array, but here we use the approach of echoing the return value to a different file descriptor and redirecting appropriately.

Comment: syntax error at line 28: `}' unexpected. I'm getting this error

Comment: Hmmm.  Works for me with version  `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`

Comment: The syntax if fragile; make sure you have all the spaces and semi-colons.